# Focus function on highcharts not working in mozilla

Tags: highcharts

I have done tabbing fucntionality which is working in both ie and chrome but it is not working mozilla

fiddle [here][1]

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/28Lrysmj/
```

Comment: Tabbing functionality ?

Comment: keyboard tab key functionality..
Check in chrome when i do press tab key...
please put the code in ur local server as jsfiddle doesnot show tab key functionality

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't related to highcharts. It seem to be plugin/extension related issue in Mozilla. Try  running your page in safe mode . refer following article [Tabbing not working in Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/956153)

Comment: I have tried opening in safe mode but i didnt find success can u help me to fix the issue